# Java If /Else statement Command String

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, draw

So I am new to coding and am taking a course for it right now. I am trying to have the code I am writing take a string like  and make a turtle image move or draw based on the commands, I am using a for loop but whenever I input the command string it executes the movements in a weird order.

```
int stringLength = commands.length();

for(int i=0; i<stringLength ;i++) {
    if (thigny.contains("F")) {

        rabbit.forward(move);

    } else if (thigny.contains("f")) {

        rabbit.penUp();
        rabbit.forward(move);

    } else if (thingy.contains("+")) {
        rabbit.turnLeft();
    } else if (thingy.contains("-")) {
        rabbit.turnRight();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In each iteration of the loop you check if the string contains some character, anywhere in it, regardless of its position. Instead, you should iterate over the characters of the string and check them individually. E.g.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
    char ch = commands.charAt(i);
    if (ch == 'F') {
        rabbit.forward(forwardPixels);
    } else if (ch == 'f') {
        rabbit.penUp();
        rabbit.forward(forwardPixels);
    } else if (ch == '+') {
        rabbit.turnLeft();
    } else if (ch == '-') {
        rabbit.turnRight();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `contains()` method try comparing each  character one by one using `commands.charAt(i)`. Contains method return true if anywhere in the  string provided parameter contains. That is why your rabbit if only doing forwarding I guess.

Example:

```
 for(int i=0; i<stringLength ;i++) {
            if (commands.charAt(i)=='F')) {

                rabbit.forward(forwardPixels);

            } else if (commands.charAt(i)== 'f')) {

                rabbit.penUp();
                rabbit.forward(forwardPixels);
            }
            // replace other in same way

            ....
```